# Bug in layout when I use properties from attrs.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, properties

I am trying to use two properties from attrs.xml such as: `content` and `handle`. When I use them while building the layout the view goes away. I have been trying the bug for 3 days and nothing worked.
Help is much appreciated!

**Code in Context**

```
<hh.hhh.app.android.hhhh.widget.ExpandablePanel
    android:id="@+id/expandablePanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:handle="@+id/expandButton"
    app:content="@+id/listViewProduct"
    app:collapsedHeight="50dip"
    app:animationDuration="25">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewProduct"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandButton"/>
</hh.hhh.app.android.hhhh.widget.ExpandablePanel>
```

**attrs.xml code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ExpandablePanel">
        <attr name="handle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="content" format="reference" />
        <attr name="collapsedHeight" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="animationDuration" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: what bug are you getting?

Comment: Have u added xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in your parent layot.?
Also make sure that "hh.hhh.app.android.hhhh.widget.ExpandablePanel" is correct package name

Comment: thank u for the suggestions @LvN..I made sure all those are correct before asking the question

Comment: U mean, preview in your IDE is not working?

Comment: @AkshayBhat it  **shows** blank...the ListView and the Button is not shown.

Comment: It might be the bug in IDE when you use your custom attrs. I recommend to update your IDE.

Comment: @AkshayBhat, i **don't** think that is a problem coz when I do: app:content="@id/listView", the view together with device screen goes away. I _think_ is a problem in implementation of the code which I couldnt figure out what.

Comment: Please post your Custom class to figure out the exact problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my own custom class as an example. So for all custom function you need to first check if it is in EditMode or not. `isInEditMode()` tells us is the layout is being render by IDE preview or by phone. IDE preview is not so much powerful to run our custom codes, so it is recommended to do not run our custom while rendering by preview. I am attaching my custom class to just understand the exact scenario.

```
    public class DynamicImageView extends ImageView {
    static DynamicImageTypeListener masterImageTypeListener;
    DynamicImageTypeListener imageTypeListener;
    int imageResourceArray;

    public DynamicImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attr, defStyle);
        initValues(attr, defStyle);
    }

    public DynamicImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        initValues(attr, 0);
    }

    public DynamicImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static void setMasterImageTypeListener(DynamicImageTypeListener masterImageTypeListener) {
        DynamicImageView.masterImageTypeListener = masterImageTypeListener;
    }

    public void setImageTypeListener(DynamicImageTypeListener imageTypeListener) {
        this.imageTypeListener = imageTypeListener;
    }

    private void initValues(AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {  //This code will run only on phone not by preview.
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attr, R.styleable.DynamicImageView, defStyle, 0);
            imageResourceArray = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
            updateImage();
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void updateImage() {
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(imageResourceArray);
        int imageIndex = imageTypeListener != null ? imageTypeListener.getImageType(getContext()) : (masterImageTypeListener != null ? masterImageTypeListener.getImageType(getContext()) : 0);
        setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(imageIndex, -1));
    }
}
```

Hope it will help :)